# How to crawl data from the new tab opening

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape, scrapy-selenium

I'm trying to crawl the detail of product of this webpage https://www.goo-net.com/php/search/summary.php by scrapy-selenium.

Because I want to crawl the detail information of each product, I crawled all url of product from the page. Then I use callback method to parse it into another def to crawl all the information of that url.

But I try a lot of solutions but my output always not showing anything

Here is my code

```
import scrapy
import selenium
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class Goonet1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'goonet1'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest (
            url='https://www.goo-net.com/php/search/summary.php',
            wait_time=4,
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath("//*[@class='heading_inner']/h3/a")
        url_detail = []
        for link in links:
            url = response.urljoin(link.xpath(".//@href").get())
            url_detail.append(url)
        for i in url_detail:
            yield SeleniumRequest (
                url=i,
                wait_time=4,
                callback=self.parse_item
            )

    def parse_item(self,response):
        base_price = response.xpath("//table[@class='mainData']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/span/text()").get()
        yield {
            'base_price': base_price
        }
```

Here is my settings.py

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}

#SELENIUM
from shutil import which
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['-headless']  # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

**Add BaseURL to url_detail to complete your link:**

```
def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath("//*[@class='heading_inner']/h3/a")
        url_detail = []
        for link in links:
            url = response.urljoin(link.xpath(".//@href").get())
            url_detail.append(url)
        for i in url_detail:
            link = "https://www.goo-net.com" + i
            yield SeleniumRequest (
                url=link,
                wait_time=4,
                callback=self.parse_item
            )
```